# Overriding ZF2 global/local config: unsetting

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've run into a problem where my local config overrides global but I need local to *remove* not just override.

E.g.

```
// global.php
'mail_transport' => [
    'type' => 'Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp',
    'options' => [
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'connectionClass' => 'login',
        'connectionConfig' => [
            // ...
        ],
    ],
], // ...
```

---

```
// local.php
'mail_transport' => [
    'type' => 'Zend\Mail\Transport\File',
    'options' => [
        'path' => 'data/mail/',
    ]
],
// ...
```

So, `mail_transport` is being overridden, yet its options `host`, `port`, `connectionClass` remain and muck up the mail transport factory.  Is there any way to override as I'd like?  Or is the only way to edit global.php directly?

Comment: Did you try just setting the values to null in the local config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener on the event `Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG` to [remove the required options](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/config.advanced.html).

> `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener` triggers a special event, `Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG`, after merging all configuration, but prior to it being passed to the ServiceManager. By listening to this event, you can inspect the merged configuration and manipulate it.

Such a listener could look like this.

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\InitProviderInterface;

class Module implements InitProviderInterface
{
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $events = $moduleManager->getEventManager();
        $events->attach(ModuleEvent::EVENT_MERGE_CONFIG, [$this, 'removeMailOptions']);
    }

    public function removeMailOptions(ModuleEvent $event)
    {
        $listener = $event->getConfigListener();
        $config = $listener->getMergedConfig(false);

        if (isset($config['mail_transport']['type'])) {
            switch($config['mail_transport']['type']) {
                case \Zend\Mail\Transport\File::class :
                    $config['mail_transport']['options'] = [
                        'path' => $config['mail_transport']['options']['path']
                    ];
                break;
            }
        }
        $listener->setMergedConfig($config);
    }
}
```